# Ruby OpenURI allow redirections from https to http

Tags: ruby, open-uri

The Ruby open-uri library [blocks redirections](https://github.com/ruby/open-uri/blob/343464b0a419ea33fb1461471297501a4ae9d2fa/lib/open-uri.rb#L226) from https to http with the error

> RuntimeError (redirection forbidden: https://link -> http://link)

Is there any way to modify this behavior to allow these redirects? Of course monkey patching `OpenURI.redirectable?` seems an obvious option but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible. Are there any other options here? Most existing answers suggest [open_uri_redirections](https://github.com/open-uri-redirections/open_uri_redirections) but this gem is unmaintained and no longer works.

Comment: From the comments in the source code for `redirectable?` : `# https to http redirect is also forbidden intentionally.(...)# However this is ad hoc.  It should be extensible/configurable.`

Comment: How about using a better tool like Net::HTTP or any of HTTP client gems? OpenURI is probally the worst part of the Ruby standard library as its so easy to creat remote code execution vulnerabilities with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open_uri_redirections` gem does nothing special but monkey patching `OpenURI.redirectable?` in an ugly stateful way.

*If the security consideration doesn't apply* (i.e. you don't send cookies/referer) - just rewrite it.

```rb
def OpenURI.redirectable?(uri1, uri2)
  uri1.scheme.downcase == uri2.scheme.downcase ||
  (/\A(?:https?|ftp)\z/i =~ uri1.scheme && /\A(?:https?|ftp)\z/i =~ uri2.scheme)
end
```

The only change for this function was in time of 2.4 allowing http->https, so we can assume this is very stable.

But indeed, consider more full-featured http-client instead

Comment: Seems like a solution. Ended up switching to HTTParty though.